# How to select two elements inside a div in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a div with class `footer-contact` and inside that div, I have several `input` and `textarea` elements. I want to empty their text. I tried using the following selector but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(".footer-contact input[type=text] textarea").val('');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".footer-contact,input[type=text],textarea").val('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='footer-contact' value='asdas'>
<input type='text' value='asdas'>
<textarea>asdas</textarea>
```

1. add comma
2. if there is no comma it will look for child

Comment: I have one confusion, Will this select all `textarea` elements or only those which are inside `footer-contact`?

Comment: this will select element with class footer-contact , all textarea , all input type text @HumaAli

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$(".footer-contact input[type=text], .footer-contact textarea").each(function(){
    this.value = "";
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! The accepted answer is wrong because it will select all footer-contact class, all textareas and all input texts instead of the element inside footer-contact class

Answer (score 0):

First you select the container, and then you can search inside of it. You need to separate with commmas:

```
$(".footer-contact").find("input[type=text], textarea").val('');
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
var val1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[4];
var val2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[5];
$([val2, val1]).keyup(() => { }
```